# How to get catalina base path of remote server in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How can I get remote server catalina.base path like we do for local server ?

```
String catalinaBase = System.getProperty("catalina.base");
```

Comment: File configDir = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "conf");

Comment: I have 2 web applications app1 and app2. In app1 I want to get log files(which are in tomcat/logs) of app2. I am using apache-tomcat-8.5.27.

Comment: app1 and app2 are on the same server? on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your tomcat installation. `System.getProperty()` will return  values from system properties/environment variables. If your tomcat installation has set CATALINA_HOME then you can use that. Look at this [Tomcat installation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html)

If you are trying this on a server you visit this [Getting tomcat's installation directory using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708295/getting-tomcats-installation-directory-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you not to use container specific properties but to specify your own system property and start tomcat (or any other servlet container) with it:

```
-Dconfig.dir=/path/to/config
```

```
System.getProperty("config.dir");
```